# JPA TypedQuery error

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I get the error *"Cannot create TypedQuery for query with more than one return using requested result type"*

for the following query using JPA on Glassfish, any ideas what is wrong here? I want to get the latest debit record with a certain debit status.

```
 entityManager.createQuery("select dd, MAX(dd.createdMillis) from T_DEBIT dd" +              
                " where dd.debitStatus in (:debitStatus)" +
                " and dd.account = :account" , Debit.class)
                .setParameter("debitStatus", false)
                .setParameter("account", account)
                .getSingleResult();
```

Comment: Post your TypedQuery declaration

Comment: I hope the answer I provided helps, is a little early here so let me know if you have questions regarding my answer.  Basically, you are trying to return an Entity but have selected only two columns, which does not constitute an entity

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A generic parameter is normally specified for a `TypedQuery`.  If you declared a `TypedQuery` you would use an `Object[]` as the generic parameter for the `TypedQuery`, since you are projecting columns and not returning a complete entity.

However, since you have not declared a `TypedQuery` (your using a concise coding style), you need to change `Debit.class` to `Object[].class` since your not selecting an object, but instead only two fields.

```
 Object[] result = entityManager.createQuery("select dd, MAX(dd.createdMillis) from T_DEBIT dd" +              
                " where dd.debitStatus in (:debitStatus)" +
                " and dd.account = :account" , Object[].class) //Notice change
                .setParameter("debitStatus", false)
                .setParameter("account", account)
                .getSingleResult();
```

Executing this query will return a `Object[]` where each index in the `Object[]` corresponds with a field in your select statement.  For example:

```
result[0] = dd
result[1] = max(dd.createdMillis)
```

To avoid using the `Object[]` you could create a new class to retrieve these values in a more strongly typed fashion.  Something like:

```
public class Result {

    String dd;
    Date createdMillis;

    public Result(String dd, Date createdMillis) {
        super();
        this.dd = dd;
        this.createdMillis = createdMillis;
    }

    public String getDd() {
        return dd;
    }

    public void setDd(String dd) {
        this.dd = dd;
    }

    public Date getCreatedMillis() {
        return createdMillis;
    }

    public void setCreatedMillis(Date createdMillis) {
        this.createdMillis = createdMillis;
    }

}
```

Then in your JPQL statement you could call the constructor:

```
Result result = entityManager.createQuery("select NEW fully.qualified.Result(dd, MAX(dd.createdMillis)) from T_DEBIT dd" +              
                " where dd.debitStatus in (:debitStatus)" +
                " and dd.account = :account" , Result.class)
                .setParameter("debitStatus", false)
                .setParameter("account", account)
                .getSingleResult();
```

Recently, I have blogged about this exact topic.  I encourage you to view this video tutorial I created: https://tothought.cloudfoundry.com/post/16

Comment: tnx, when i use Object[] result=entity.. I get error that it can not convert

Comment: @Spring did you change the class specified in the createQuery method from Debit.class to Object[].class?  I put a comment `//notice change` at this point in the code in the answer.

Comment: @Spring did that remedy the exception?

Comment: tnx solved! one minor issue, it gives me the first record instead of latest one, wtf?

Comment: I also noticed that the long time value at Object[1] i snot the same time value of objcet[0] entity, so something is fishy here?

Comment: Maybe you need to do a group by with a having clause?

Comment: I solved the problem by simply using an order by desc, instead of MAX